# Can you / how do you add a constructor into an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, enzyme

**Is it possible to add a constructor to an object?**

If the following were possible, I would like to accomplish something like:

```
const constructorObject = {
  Constructor: Constructor("content")
}
```

If this object were accessed you would be able to do the following:

```
new constructorObject.constructor({ content: "content" }):
```

without getting an error saying:

```
undefined is not a constructor 
(evaluating 'new constructorObject.Constructor({ content: "content })')
```

For context, I have a `react` component, and I'm making a call to the googleAPI in a `parent` component.

`this.googleAPI` is passed to the `child`. 
When I'm running the test - `props` are passed to the `child` but without a `constructor` in the object - the test fails.

In the `childComponent` the `init` is called on `mount`:

```
init() {
   const { position, map, title, icon } = this.props;
   this.marker = new this.props.googleApi.Marker({
     icon,
     position,
     map,
     title
   });
}
```

In the Enzyme test:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Child from "src/components/child";

describe("components/child", () => {
  let props;
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      googleApi: {},
      map: {},
      position: {
        lat: 10,
        lng: 10
      },
      title: "title",
      icon: "icon"
    };
  });

  describe("on mount", () => {
    it("should render into the document", () => {
      const component = shallow(<Marker {...props} />);
      expect(component).to.not.be.null;
    });
  });
});
```

This is the `enzyme` error:

```
undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new this.props.googleApi.Marker({ title: this.props.title })')
```

Comment: can you post your test code for more clarity? one would usually mock the external resources eg: using `jest`. in this case i would assume that would be `googleAPI`

Comment: I like the idea of mocking the call...is there unique way to handle that when a constructor is being called?

Comment: using `jest` give this a try `googleApi: {Marker: jest.fn()}` when initializing props in `beforeEach`

Comment: This works beautifully - but is it possible to add an event listener into the spy so the component could then call this.marker.addListener('click', () => {})

Comment: i updated it as answer as they are more often read than comments.

Answer (score 1):

One would usually mock the external resources using something like [jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started). in this case i would assume that would be `googleAPI`.

When initializing props in `beforeEach`,

if you want to add an `addListener` **that is a constructor** within your `Marker` I would try :

```
let props;
let component;
beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      googleApi: {
        Marker: () => ({ addListener: jest.fn() })
      },
    };
    component = shallow(<Marker {...props} />);
});
```

If you just need a function you can do:

```
props = {
      googleApi: {
        ChildComponent: () => ({ click: jest.fn() }),
        event: {
          addListener: jest.fn()
        }
      }
    }
```

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In JS a constructor can be just a function. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#Examples). Basically this should work for you:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  props = {
    googleApi: {
      Marker: () => {}
    },
    map: {},
    position: {
      lat: 10,
      lng: 10
    },
    title: "title",
    icon: "icon"
  };
});
```